# How do I combine the values in two different columns with same names?

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, multiple-columns

I have a matrix that has multiple columns with different names but some of them are the same and I want to group them together, then take the mean of those columns.

Basically,

```
Lung Lung Lung Heart Heart Heart Kidney Kidney Kidney Liver Liver Liver
 3     7   9     1     2     1     8      9      12     15    17    19
```

I want the matrix above to look like this

```
Lung Heart Kidney Liver
 3     1      8     15
 7     2      9     17
 9     1      12    19
```

Then I am planning to get the mean of each column (Lung, Heart etc.)

So, it would also be fine if you suggest a code that calculates the means of the columns that have the same names without even combining them.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `split`

```
data.frame(lapply(split.default(df1, names(df1)), unlist, use.names = FALSE))
#   Heart Kidney Liver Lung
#1     1      8    15    3
#2     2      9    17    7
#3     1     12    19    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method with `matrix` to organize the values into columns and `setNames` to add the variable names. Note that this requires that the variables with the same name are of equal size and are adjacent.

```
setNames(data.frame(matrix(unlist(dat), 3)), unique(names(dat)))
  Lung Heart Kidney Liver
1    3     1      8    15
2    7     2      9    17
3    9     1     12    19
```

Also, this solution works with a data.frame rather than a matrix, because this is the structure presented in the question, but the same code will work with a matrix without any alterations.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Lung = 3L, Lung = 7L, Lung = 9L, Heart = 1L, Heart = 2L, 
    Heart = 1L, Kidney = 8L, Kidney = 9L, Kidney = 12L, Liver = 15L, 
    Liver = 17L, Liver = 19L), .Names = c("Lung", "Lung", "Lung", 
"Heart", "Heart", "Heart", "Kidney", "Kidney", "Kidney", "Liver", 
"Liver", "Liver"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L
))
```